# CrossHair Tracing In JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I was able to implement real-time mouse tracing as follow :

[image]

The source code is as follow :

http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/jstock/src/org/yccheok/jstock/charting/CrossHairUI.java?revision=1.5&view=markup

http://jstock.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jstock/jstock/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/ChartJDialog.java?revision=1.9&view=markup

However, I unable to obtained the correct y screen coordinate, when an subplot being added.

[(broken image)](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/notok.png)

I suspect I didn't get the correct screen data area.

When there is only one plot in the screen, I get a screen data area with height 300++

When a sub plot added to the bottom, I expect screen data area height will be reduced, due to the height occupied by the newly added subplot.

However, I have no idea how to obtain the correct screen data area for the first plot.

```
final XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) cplot.getSubplots().get(0);

// Shall I get _plotArea represents screen for getSubplots().get(0)?
// How?
// I try
//
// chartPanel.getScreenDataArea(0, 0);
// chartPanel.getScreenDataArea(0, 1);
// chartPanel.getScreenDataArea(1, 0);
// chartPanel.getScreenDataArea(1, 1);
//
// All returned null

// OK. I suspect this is causing me unable to get the correct screen y coordinate
// I always get the same _plotArea, although a new sub plot had been added.
final Rectangle2D _plotArea = chartPanel.getScreenDataArea();

final RectangleEdge rangeAxisEdge = plot.getRangeAxisEdge();

final double yJava2D = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(yValue, _plotArea, rangeAxisEdge);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet to obtained the correct rectangle after dive into JFreeChart source code.

```
/* Try to get correct main chart area. */
final Rectangle2D _plotArea = chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(0).getDataArea();
```