# How to show pointer while Mouse tracing in jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am able to do mouse tracing in jfreechart and show tooltip value. Can anyone tell me how i display pointer on graph while mouse tracing. see the pointer on graph in the link picture.

[CrossHair Tracing Problem In JFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204383/crosshair-tracing-problem-in-jfreechart)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do Mouse Tracing in Jfreechart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441214/how-to-do-mouse-tracing-in-jfreechart)